# pg-pool with typescript, can't create Pool object

Tags: node.js

I have a node project in which I'm using the `pg-pool` library. I've included the following in my dependencies:

```
"@types/pg-pool": "0.0.3",
"pg": "^7.3.0",
"pg-format": "^1.0.4",
"pg-pool": "^2.0.3",
```

In one of my files I've tried creating a `Pool` object using the following:

```
import {PoolConfig, Pool} from "pg-pool";
import config from "./config";

const pool = new Pool(config);
```

When I try to execute this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: pg_pool_1.Pool is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer to this was to avoid using `pg-pool` and opt for `pg` directly, the code now looks like:

```
import {PoolConfig, Pool} from "pg";
```

Then the dependencies:

```
"@types/pg": "^7.1.2",
"pg": "^7.3.0",
"pg-format": "^1.0.4",
"pg-pool": "^2.0.3",
```